# The tour page should talk about questions being placed "on hold" rather than being "closed"

Tags: discussion, bug, closed-questions, tour

The tour page on all non-meta sites (e.g. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)) currently contains the following blurb in its "do-not-ask" section:

> *Questions that need improvement may be **closed** until someone fixes them.*

Quite some time ago, SE decided that questions that received five close votes would have their status described as "on hold" for a while ([five days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/259700)) before switching to being "closed" (instead of being labeled "closed" immediately). If I'm not mistaken, this was done because "on hold" implies that the status is temporary (which it is, pending fixes), not permanent.

This being the case, I think that this blurb should also refer to questions being placed on hold, particularly given that the point of this blurb is "you *can* fix your questions, and once you do, you can get answers". Suggestion:

> *Questions that need improvement may be **placed on hold** until someone fixes them.*

Comment: Five days, not a week. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/259700

Answer (score 7):

It's technically correct, given that a question being "on-hold" is technically "closed", it's just *labelled* "on-hold" for the first 5 days.

But as "closed" sounds more final, where "on-hold" sounds like a state where changes can be made, I agree a change should be made to the tour page.

However, I suggest using both to avoid further confusion, because a question could actually be put on hold *or* closed, and in either case can be improved and re-opened. And we don't want people to think otherwise or be mislead/confused by what they read in the tour page when they first arrived.

**Suggest:**

> *Questions that need improvement may be placed on-hold or closed until someone fixes them*